# XML3D: XFLOW syntax

Tags: javascript, xml3d

I have two question regarding XFLOW syntax:

1. Can I use xflow data gained from  `<assetdata>`node?
2. What is the difference between `<data>` and `<assetdata>` it seem that those two have the same functionalities. Or in the other words does assetdata node is considered **DataContainer**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the main difference between `<data>` and `<assetdata>` is the `includes` attribute, which can reference another `<assetdata>`'s `name` attribute and is scoped to the enclosing `<asset>`. It was designed this way to make it possible to nest assets or declare many assets in the same document without having to worry about making sure all the IDs they may use are unique (like you would if you were to use the `src` attribute of `<data>` elements, which reference an HTML ID).

The other differences are:

- You can't nest `<assetdata>` elements. You can get the same functionality using their `includes` attribute though.
- `<assetdata>` elements can only be used inside an `<asset>` element

Aside from that they work like `<data>` elements do, you can give them compute operators or nest other data inside them or overwrite data like you would with `<data>` elements. They may even be merged in a future version of XML3D.

Have a look at the [recursive asset example](http://xml3d.github.io/xml3d-examples/examples/recursiveAsset/recursive.html) for a more complicated use case.